# visual studio 2005 command window 'of' autocomplete opens on wrong side

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

[image: Command Window issue]

Hi everyone, I have a weird problem I can't figure out how to solve. I inherited a co-worker's computer, and on his visual studio 2005 in the command window, when I use the 'of' command, the auto-complete window that opens appears to grow to the left rather than to the right. This makes it impossible to see the start of any of the strings, because I keep the command window on the left side of my screen. This never used to happen on my old machine. He also had all his context menus opening to the left, but I fixed that in control panel and it didn't do anything to this. Restarting the computer didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the localisation of the machine? Has it been set to a right-to-left text format? Additionally, is it just `of` that causes this or all commands? Do you see similar in other combo boxes eg the Start->Run Command?

Comment: I thought about localization, and it's possible it's related to that since my old co-worker spoke Arabic, but the localization settings currently at least on the machine are all left->right and English. All commands in the Command Window use the same auto-complete, so they all do this. My context menus are all fine. I'm running Windows 7, so I don't have Start->Run combo box. Other basic combo boxes work fine.

Comment: FWIW You can enable a Start->Run in Start menu settings but it's a little irrelavant. Arabic definitely sounds like it's likely to be the cause, being RTL. I'm afraid I can't suggest where to look next. Hopefully someone else can.